# Есть идея для App Store, как проверить оригинальность

Tags: ios, appstore

Добрый день! Есть идея приложения, подскажите, как умно проверить оригинальность, кроме тупого просмотра темы App Store. Спасибо!

Comment: А как вы представляете себе автоматизированную проверку приложений на наличие/реализацию идеи?

Comment: Всё уже написано до нас.

Answer (score 1):

Вижу два пути.

Первый — это поиск по ключевым словам в Апсторе. Нужно попробовать поиск с разными ключевыми словами, потому что Апстор не индексирует описание программ, а только название, а также список keywords, которые указывает разработчик (а там до 100 символов всего).

Второй вариант — это поиск гуглом по Апстору. Гугл индексирует также и описание программ. Например:

https://www.google.com/search?q=time+manager+site%3Aitunes.apple.com

Можно ускорить поиск, если переключиться в режим "Картинки", тогда сразу видно о чем программа: https://goo.gl/au0LXx

Comment: Спасибо, пробую!